# Printing object attributes on one line

Tags: python, formatting

I've got a list called "location" with two class-created objects inside:

```
location = [rat1,rat2]
```

I'd like to print an attribute of both rats on one line, while keeping the location list dynamic. I have this currently:

```
for i in range(0,len(location)):
    print((location[i].vname),sep=',')
```

This iterates through the lists items, and prints the "vname" attribute for every object in the list it sees. Unfortunately this currently returns:

```
Young Rat
Adult Rat
```

If I change sep to end, it prints this:

```
Young Rat,Adult Rat,
```

It's almost as if the sep isn't even registered at all in the print. Does anyone have any ideas? Also, sorry for any formatting issues, this is my first time posting on stack exchange.

Comment: `sep` would be put between separate positional arguments to `print` - you are only passing a single positional argument. Try e.g. `print('foo', 'bar', 'baz', sep=',')` to see it working.

Comment: As an aside, it is usually not necessary to do `range(len(lst))` in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make one call to print and join the various attributes using `str.join`. The following should work:

```
print(','.join(rat.vname for rat in location))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `print ','.join(location)` or `print ','.join(map(str, location))`

More generally, don't iterate using an integer variable in python.

Comment: The OP is joining an attribute, not the actual object. Depending on how/if the OP defined `__str__`, this will probably not be what they want.